# Parsing content with the HTML Agility Pack and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i am trying to get significant content for searched keywords in html.

using the code below for generate a HtmlNodeCollection

```
var findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//*[not(self::script)]").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("SearchedKeywordText") && x.InnerHtml.Contains("SearchedKeyword1Text")).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                string FirstContent = findclasses.First().InnerText;
```

And i am getting this result

> - Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
> - [0] Name: "div"}    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [1] Name: "div"}    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [2] Name: "div"}    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [3] Name: "ul"} HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [4] Name: "li"} HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [5] Name: "span"}   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [6] Name: "span"}   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [7] Name: "div"}    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [8] Name: "span"}   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [9] Name: "span"}   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [10]    Name: "ul"} HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
> - [11]    Name: "li"} HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode

But when i want to simple modify the code to get string from outside:

```
string search1 = "SearchedKeywordText";
string search2 = "SearchedKeyword1Text";
..
..
var findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//*[not(self::script)]").Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains(search1) && x.InnerHtml.Contains(search2)).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                    string FirstContent = findclasses.First().InnerText;
```

Result:

> - Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
>         Empty   "Enumeration yielded no results"

Enumeration in first block is work good for me but after that changes it does not work. Is there any idea for this simple question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.First()` on an empty `IEnumerable`

You could use `.Any()` to check if findclasses is not empty

```
if (findclasses.Any())
{
   string firstContent = findclasses.First().InnerText;
}
```

- Why is it empty?

maybe there are results but there is a case mistmatch and you need to make your search case insensitive, for that rather than

```
x.InnerHtml.Contains(search1)
```

you can do something like:

```
x.InnerHtml.IndexOf(search1,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)>=0
```

that will return true if the search keyword is found regardless of the letter case.